Apache/2.4.60 (Unix) - competing location Matches
I need to define two seperate locationMatches in apache, where the first location captures a subset of the second location. However, it is crucial that once the first location match applies, the second one doesn't.
    <LocationMatch "^/abc/api/login_check">
        MellonEnable "off"
        AuthType None
        Require all granted
    </LocationMatch>
    
    <LocationMatch "^/abc_but_not_followed_by_api/login_check">
    ...
    </LocationMatch>

How would I do that?
